# How does 3scale API Gateway communicate with portal?

Tags: redhat, 3scale

I am trying out 3Scale API Management. I would like to have the API gateway running on-premise in Docker container and test with 3Scale API Portals by Red Hat evaluation.

A few questions:

**How are the communication done between API Gateway and API Portal?**

Is it the API gateway that request the configuration at startup from API Portal or is it API Portal that pushes the configuration to the gateway?
Reason of thinking is that the API Gateway is behind firewall(s) and to communicate to internet (API Portal) it uses a proxy.

If API Gateway communicates with API Portal - **how can I configure proxy server in with Docker?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in another forum:

> The communication between the API Gateway and the API Manager uses two
>   APIs : 
>    - the Service Management API to ask for authorization and report usage
>    - the Account Management API (read-only) to get the list of available APIs and their configuration
>
> The Service Management API is at su1.3scale.net (port 443) whereas the
>   Account Management API is at
>
> The configuration is retrieved by polling the Account Management API.

For reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/3scale-api-management-by-red-hat/EXhrVUfKOtY